# Intersection/Union of Language of PDA, CFG and NFA

Tags: regular-languages, automata, context-free

I stumbled across the following question.

Say I have given an arbitrary PDA $P$, NFA $N$, and CFG $G$. My question is then if the following language ($L(P) \cap L(N)) \cup L(G)$ is context-free.

How can this be determined?

Comment: "without knowing the individual languages" should not be surprising -- most of mathematics deals with numbers/functions/sets and proves results on those without knowing what they exactly are, and CS is no different. E.g. we can prove $n+n$ to be even without knowing what $n$ exactly is.

Comment: @chi I meant without knowing the properties of the individual languages.

Comment: @chi But we can't prove that $m+n$ is even without knowing more about $m$ and $n$. So while I agree that it's not surprising that one can know this kind of thing without knowing the languages, it's certainly a legitimate question.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Surely the question is legitimate! But in this case, we do know more about the languages, namely that they are related to a PDA, NFA and CFG. That is enough to prove the thesis, even if we do not know what are those automata/grammars. I only wanted to stress that, when writing proofs, we often do not know the exact values of our variables, but merely know they satisfy some properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$L(P)$ and $L(G)$ are context-free; $L(N)$ is regular.  By [standard closure properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language#Closure), the intersection of a context-free language with a regular language is context-free, and the union of two context-free languages is context-free. Therefore, $L(P)\cap L(N)$ is some context-free language $C$ and $C\cup L(G)$ is context free.

The closure properties can be proven without reference to the specific language by using the fact that every context-free language is accepted by a PDA or defined by a context-free grammar.  For example, to show that the union of two context-free languages is context free, let those languages be defined by grammars $G_1$ and $G_2$ with start symbols $S_1$ and $S_2$. We can rename the non-terminals in $G_1$ and $G_2$ so that no non-terminal appears in both grammars. Now form the a grammar $G$ with start symbol $S$ consisting of the rule $S\to S_1|S_2$, all the rules of $G_1$ and all the rules of&nbsp:$G_2$.  You should be able to convince yourself that $L(G) = L(G_1)\cup L(G_2)$. But proving this didn't require us to know anything about what rules are contained in the grammars.